# Plotting OHLC charts in python with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a list of candlestick objects, each one has 6 values (open, high, low, close, volume, timestamp). I want to use matplotlib.finance.candlestick2_ohlc(ax, opens, highs, lows, closes, width=4, colorup='k', colordown='r', alpha=0.75) function to plot this data. The thing is, how can i subdivide my list into opens, highs, lows and closes in order to load it to this function?

Here's my candlestick class:

```
class Candle:
#Candlestick chart object
def __init__(self, open, high, low, close, volume, timeStamp):
    self.open = open
    self.high = high
    self.low = low
    self.close = close
    self.volume = volume
    self.timestamp = timeStamp

def __str__(self):
    return """
    Open: %s
    High: %s
    Low: %s
    Close: %s
    Volume : %s
    Timestamp: %s""" %(self.open, self.high, self.low, self.close, self.volume, self.timestamp)
```

And this is my list construction methods:

```
def getTradeHistory(self, timeFrame, symbol, count):
    #Get the trade history from the API

    return self.client.Trade.Trade_getBucketed(binSize=timeFrame, partial=True, symbol=symbol, reverse=False, count=count).result()

def constructCandles(self, th):
    #Iterate through list of trade history items and store them as candles in a list

    for candle in th :
        self.candles.append(Candle(candle['open'], candle['high'], candle['low'], candle['close'], candle['volume'], candle['timestamp']))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say your list of candlestick objects is called my_candles then:

```
opens = [candle.open for candle in my_candles]
highs = [candle.high for candle in my_candles]
lows = [candle.low for candle in my_candles]
closes = [candle.close for candle in my_candles]
```

Now you have lists for opens, closes, highs and lows you can call matplotlib.finance.candlestick2_ohlc

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.finance as mpf

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,5))
mpf.candlestick2_ochl(ax, opens, closes, highs, lows, width=4, colorup='k', colordown='r', alpha=0.75)
```

Also note that matplotlib.finance is deprecated in 2.0.